# Selenium web driver: unable to locate element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am New to selenium: I have this source and am trying click on a button using xpath with selenium webdriver. This is the button(last line in the html) that am trying to click on:

I use this xpath: `"//div[@id='innerBody']/div[4]/div/div/ul/li[3]/button"`
and it gives me unable to locate element.

Any idea why and how I should go about it.

```
<document>
<html class="FullPage" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="">
<head>
<body class="brand brand-mastwide FullPage no-footer width-hd" style="">
<div id="cboxOverlay" style="display: none;"/>
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="padding-bottom: 2px; padding-right: 2px; display: none;">
<div id="masthead" class="masthead full-width">
<div id="toast-absolute" class="full-width">
<!-- Content -->
<div id="outer-outer" class="with-nav">
<div id="outer-wrapper" class="full-width">
<a name="pageTop"/>
<div class="main-wrapper">
<div class="inner">
<div id="applicationHost">
<div data-bind="router: router" data-view="_App/AppShell" style="" data-active-view="true">
<div class="durandal-wrapper" data-view="_App/Home/HomeShell" style="" data-active-view="true">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/cache/sf/_App/Home/HomeShell.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/cache/sf/css/lib/joyride-2.1.css"/>
<div id="regionMain" class="clear-block with-side with-side-left" data-bind="css:{'clear-block with-side with-side-left': ShowLeftNavigation()}">
<div class="content-pane main">
<div class="inner-content-pane main">
<div data-bind="compose: Message"/>
<div class="router" data-bind="router: router">
<div class="durandal-wrapper" data-view="_App/Home/Filebox/Filebox" style="" data-active-view="true">
<h1 data-bind="text: Title">Bestandsvak voor satish vanahalli</h1>
<link href="/cache/f69bb3f534fb459062226526576bc4dea7e8fe7e/css/lib/jqui/jquery-ui-1.10.0.sf.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<br/>
<div id="innerBody" class="file-box-container">
<div class="errortip" data-bind="text: ErrorMessage, visible: ErrorMessage" style="display: none;"/>
<div class="clear-block">
<div class="upload-button">
<div data-bind="compose: FileList">
<div class="c-content" data-view="_App/Home/Common/FileList/FileList" style="" data-active-view="true">
<div class="secondary-ctrl btnl-row title-noborder clear-block" data-bind="css: { hidden: !ShowSecondary }">
<ul class="context-actions" data-bind="visible: Capabilities.AllowCheckboxes, foreach: CurrentActions">
<li class="hover-list">
<li class="hover-list">
<li class="hover-list">
***<button class="txt context-action" data-bind="click: Click">***
```

Comment: Have you used this xpath: ** //button[@class='txt context-action] **

Comment: This is interesting. Tried this one and it is clicking on the first button in the list. How do I target the 3rd button in the list?

Comment: How many buttons are there in your parent div tag??

Comment: Can you post other buttons html code.??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this xpath:

```
   //ul[@class='context-actions']/li[3]/button[@class='txt context-action][3]
```

Comment: Marking this as answer as the first comment almost gave me the answer. Thanks @Subh for tweaking it

Answer (score 2):

As per your comments for question, if you want to click on the **3rd button** in the list, please try below xpath; I have just tweaked **@Saritha's** :

```
(//button[@class='txt context-action'])[3]
```

This will click on the **3rd button** in the page (in the chronological order of DOM representation) with `class` as `txt context-action`.

Comment: Do I have give it in brackets? it gives me "either invalid or does not result in a web element" error

Comment: Yes.. In case you are using Java for coding, the code for clicking the element must look like this: **`driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@class='txt context-action])[3]")).click();`**

Comment: Great! its working now, It's copy paste mistake. My bad! I missed adding a single quote to this 'txt context-action] at the end. Thank you for the response Subh and @Saritha

Comment: Mark @Saritha's.. She was the first one to figure it out.. I just tweaked her answer.. And,  O'course to quote: "Ladies First".. :)

Comment: Thanks for being generous:)

Comment: Just being realistic my friend.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath:

```
//*[@id="innerBody"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[3]/button
```

Comment: Tried this one, give same error-unable to locate element

Comment: @Virus: Is the button get loaded asynchronously? With ajax maybe?